# Why Entity Framework Core resets filled navigation property to null during AddRange only for first item in range?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using the Asp Net Identity library and I've customized `IdentityUser` to have a custom navigation property called `CompanyRole` of type `ApplicationRole` here is rough structure bellow

```cs
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
  ...
  public ApplicationRole CompanyRole { get; set }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Fragment of `ApplicationUser` model configuration

```cs
builder
    .HasOne(x => x.CompanyRole)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ApplicationUser>(au => au.CompanyRoleId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

So when I try to add multiple users with existing roles like this

```cs
var viewerRole = await _rolesService.GetViewerRole() // it queries role from dbcontex behind the scene, so it should be tracked 

var usersToAdd = emails.Select(email => new ApplicationUser
    {
        FirstName = request.Name,
        Email = email,
        CompanyRole = viewerRole
    }
 )

_dbContext.Set<ApplicationUser>().AddRange(usersToAdd)
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It complaints that cannot insert NULL in CompanyRoleId column, since it's a FK constraint.

The reason of this exception is that first user in a range gets CompanyRole as null, whereas others users are good. Why it's happening, since viewer role should have been tracked ?

I've tryed to play with Entities states, such as Added and Attach entity again - no luck

I've expected that all users are created with reference to existing `ApplicationRole`

BTW the workaround that worked, was if I split users adding one by one with slight changes and detach those immediately then it works, the drawback is that query per user...inefficient

```cs
var result = _dbContext.Set<ApplicationUser>().Add(user);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
_dbContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are defining the relationship between user and company role as One to One. This means any 1 company role can be assigned to only one user. So as it tries to associate the role to each user, it would de-associate it from the previous.

What it looks like you want is a Many-to-one, many users can hold the same role. Adjust your mapping to:

```
builder
    .HasOne(x => x.CompanyRole)
    .Withmany()
    .HasForeignKey<ApplicationUser>(au => au.CompanyRoleId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

... and you should be sorted.

Comment: I probably then need to remove HasForeignKey, since he's complaining. @steve-py

Comment: thanks a lot, good catch I haven't caught that issue :) I've slightly changed to

builder
                .HasOne(x => x.CompanyRole)
                .WithMany(r => r.CompanyUsers)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Comment: yup, if there is a collection on the other end that would be the mapping. 1-to-many mappings can be configured from either end, 1-to-many or many-to-1. Normally if you want bi-directional or "ownership" (delete cascade decisions) then it's more clear to configure it from the "one" side, so Company `builder.HasMany(x => x.CompanyUsers).WithOne(). Many-to-1 mappings are typically more "reference" where the "one" side doesn't care about the many. I.e. Order (many) and OrderType (one) OrderType doesn't need an Orders collection, orders just reference a common relationship to a type.

Comment: And it works like a charm Thanks a lot Steve!!!!!!your rock I missed it, looked it million times and didn't care haha, thanks !